# DeleteFunction(Long) in DatabaseHelper Cannot be applied to java.lang.String

Tags: android, listview

Good Day, I'm new to android development and i practice CRUD operation but i got an error in deleting the the selected item on my List View and i want to Update the list view after deleting.

Here's my code for deleting in Database Helper

```
public void deletegroce(int groceId){
    String groceid[] = {String.valueOf(groceId)};
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqdb.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_GROCE_ID + " = ?", groceid);
    sqdb.close();
}
```

}

And this is my code for my list

```
public class Grocery_list extends Activity {
ListView lvGorc;
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grocery_list);
    lvGorc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGroc);
    dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(Grocery_list.this);
    final ArrayList<String> aList = dbhelper.getAllGroceries();
    ArrayAdapter<String> La = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, aList);
    lvGorc.setAdapter(La);


    lvGorc.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Grocery_list.this);
            adb.setTitle("Option");
            adb.setMessage("What do you want to do?");
            adb.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
            adb.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dbhelper.deletegroce(i);

                }
            });
            adb.show();
        }
    });
    La.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvGorc.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Grocery_list.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage(aList.get(position));
            adb.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dbhelper.deletegroce(aList.get(position));
                }
            });
            adb.show();
            return  true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Could you please post the logcat error that you’re getting, I believe it could be the line sqdb.delete() but not entirely sure

Comment: @Brandon log cat says compilation error and the error is at line 62 which is the dbhelper.deletegroce(aList.get(position)); . I already post all my code in Listview.

Comment: Okay. So your deletegroce() method expects a int (groceId), but your ArrayAdapter<String> get() method will return a String value, you need to use Int.parseInt(aList.get(position)) instead of just aList.get(position) in the method call :)

Comment: @Brandon Oh thank you sir, Can you please put an answer so that i can Mark it as correct and follow up question sir, how to update the listview after deleting?

Comment: You should be able to call La.notifyDataSetChanged(); to update and redraw your listView :)

Comment: isn't right sir if i code this "int blist = Integer.parseInt(aList.get(position));" then i call the "blist" in dbhelper.deletegroce(blist); next line of that sir is La.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Ah! Because your aList is final it’s values cannot be changed, if possible remove the final on your aList, then call the notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: If that does not work try calling La.clear(), La.addAll(dbHelper.getAllGroceries()); La.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181413/discussion-between-dave-and-brandon).

Comment: My apologies but I cannot log into chat at the moment because I can’t remember my password and I’m on my mobile XD

Comment: I see, it's okay sir. by the way sir After removing the Final on my aList sir i got an error says aList is accessed from within the innerclass needs to declare final i put the back the FINAL in my aList then try La.clear(); and La.addAll(dbhelper.getallgroceries()); also La.notifyDataSetChanged(); but its not working

Comment: Please check chat again as I have managed to log in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deleteGroce() method expects an int (groceId), but your ArrayAdapter get() method will return a String value, you need to use Int.parseInt(aList.get(position)) instead of just aList.get(position) in the call method :)